# How to assign an php array to a javascript array?

Tags: jquery

I have an array $lines in php. Currently I want to assign the $lines value to a javascript variable(i.e. chartLines).

The way I assigned the php array to javascript is not correct.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    $line1 = array(array("08:00","20"),array("08:00","16"),array("08:00","19"),array("08:00","17"));

    $line2 = array(array("08:00","45"),array("08:00","47"),array("08:00","49"),array("08:00","47"));

    $lines= array($line1,$line2);  
?>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var chartLines = <?php echo $lines; ?>  

                });
```

Comment: Use `var chartLines = <?php json_encode($lines); ?>;`

Comment: why don't you output your array data into the javascript itself? meaning `<? $a=''; $a.='<script> function(){ var q=".$myArray.";'; ?>` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php
    $line1 = array(array("08:00","20"),array("08:00","16"),array("08:00","19"),array("08:00","17"));

    $line2 = array(array("08:00","45"),array("08:00","47"),array("08:00","49"),array("08:00","47"));

    $lines= array($line1,$line2);  
    $json = json_encode($lines);
?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var chartLines = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo $json; ?>  ');

                });
```

Comment: i think converting array to JSON then to JS array and including Jquery is a little hard and no need for it , echo the JS array is the simplest thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
<?php
# create PHP array:
$php_array = array("one", "two", "three");

echo "<script language='JavaScript'>\n";

echo "var js_array = new Array();\n";

$ix = 0;

foreach($php_array as $key => $value)
{
echo "js_array[$key] = $value;\n";
}

echo "</script>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the json_encode PHP function suggested by others here, like this:

```
<?php
  $chartLines = array("item1" => "val1", "item2" => "val2", "item3" => "val3");
  $chartJSON = json_encode($chartLines);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var chartLines = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo $chartJSON; ?>');
</script>
```

If you need an array on the JS side too (not an object which is what parseJSON will return), you can use jQuery to do that too:

```
var chartArr = jQuery.makeArray(chartLines);
```